# Titlesec with graphics, first paragraph indented

Tags: indentation

In the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\filcenter}% format applied to label+text
  {\bfseries\huge\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge}% before the title body
  [\vspace{0ex}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{divider.pdf}}]% after the title body
  \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{2ex}
  \assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
This an indented paragraph.

\noindent This is an unindented paragraph.
\end{document}
```

The included graphics causes (I think) the first paragraph to be indented. I tried various `\noindent` in the above code, but that did not help. (Also, I couldn't figure out how `noindent` package could help.

Except manually inserting `\noindent` before the first paragraph, is there way to automate it?

Comment: use the stared version `\titlespacing*`.

Comment: I think your code is not a MWE since you did not provide the source for the file 'divider.pdf'. A MWE should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s documentation

> The starred version kills the indentation of the paragraph following
>   the title, except in **drop**, **wrap** and **runin** where this possibility does
>   not make sense.

so it's `\titlespacing*` what you need.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\filcenter}% format applied to label+text
  {\bfseries\huge\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge}% before the title body
  [\vspace{0ex}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}]% after the title body
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{2ex}
  \assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
This an indented paragraph.

\noindent This is an unindented paragraph.
\end{document}
```